# Error in Target xslt in build.xml for ecllipse

Tags: eclipse, xslt, ant, testng, build.xml

Im trying to include xslt reports in my Testng framework with ant. When I try to execute the the MakeReport target in build.xml I get some error related to classpath saying `Reference test.classpath not found` . Below is the target code for generating xslt.

```
<target name="makexsltreport">
    <delete dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt">
    </delete>
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt">
    </mkdir>
    <xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml" style="src/xslt/testng-results.xsl" out="${ws.home}/testng-xslt/index.html" 
          classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison"> 
<!-- THE ERROR IS IN ABOVE LINE -->
        <param expression="${basedir}/testng-xslt/" name="testNgXslt.outputDir" />
        <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks" />
        <param expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter" />
        <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" />
         <classpath refid="classpath"> 
        </classpath> 
    </xslt>
</target>
```

Please help on how to solve this issue. i tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

> Reference test.classpath not found

means that Ant wasn't able to find the `test.classpath` path that you have referenced with `classpathref`.  How are you defining that path?  If the `<path id="test.classpath">` is inside a target then you will need to make your `makexsltreport` target depend (directly or indirectly) on the one that defines the path.

Also you should not use *both* a `classpathref` attribute *and* a `<classpath>` element - use one or the other.

Comment: I have given the path-id outside target like this `<path id="test.c">
<fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
 </path>`  Can you tell me how to define a classpath ? I have given it as test.c . What should I actually give in there ? It is any string ?

Comment: @mac remove the `<classpath>` element inside the `xslt` task, and change the `classpathref` attribute to match the `id` of the `<path>` you've defined (i.e. `classpathref="test.c"`).